# how to create a form that can multiply itself and add multiple data at once in angular 5

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular5

I have create a form that has two field `Name` and `price`. Right now it has no problem it is easy to add data. But I want to place an `add more` button which when pressed adds one more line of input fields same as above consisting of `Name` and `price` field. This must allow the user to add multiple data at once, after they fill the data and press save all the data must be added to the database in the same order.
My current HTML:

```js
<h4> Add Product</h4>
    <form [formGroup]="productForm" >
      <mat-input-container>
        <input matInput  type="text" formControlName="name" id="name" required="" name="name" placeholder="name">
      </mat-input-container>
    
      <mat-input-container>
        <input matInput  type="text" formControlName="price" id="price" required="" name="price" placeholder="price">
      </mat-input-container>
      <button md-raised-button >
        Add More
      </button>
      <button md-raised-button  [disabled]="productForm.invalid"
              (click)="onSubmit(productForm.value)">
        SAVE
      </button>
      <button md-raised-button class="btn btn-white btn-rounded pull-right"
              (click)="DepartmentComponent()">CANCEL
      </button>
    
    </form>
```

My current TS file:

```js
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    /*import { Item } from './Item';*/
    import { NgForm }   from '@angular/forms';
    import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
    import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
    import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from "@angular/common/http";
       
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
      private productForm: FormGroup;
      private headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
      title = 'Laravel Angular 4 App';
      constructor(private _http: HttpClient,
                  private fb: FormBuilder, ) {}
      ngOnInit() {
        this._http.get('http://localhost:8000/api/products', {headers: this.headers} ).subscribe( data => {
          console.log('DATA', data);
        });
    
        this.productForm = this.fb.group({
          name: ['', Validators.required],
          price: ['', Validators.required],
        });
      }
      onSubmit(form) {
       console.log('FORM DATA', this.productForm.value);
    
        return this._http.post('http://localhost:8000/api/products', this.productForm.value, {headers: this.headers}).subscribe( data =>
          console.log('ASFASDASDAF', data));
      }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [link](https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/), this could be done using `FormArray` as Follows

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.productForm= this.formBuilder.group({
    items: this.formBuilder.array([ this.createItem() ])
  });
}
```

and each item group should be as follows

```
createItem(): FormGroup {
  return this.formBuilder.group({
    name: '',
    price: ''
  });
}
```

and to add form dynamically

```
addItem(): void {
  this.items = this.productForm.get('items') as FormArray;
  this.items.push(this.createItem());
}
```

and the template

```
<div formArrayName="items"
  *ngFor="let item of productForm.get('items').controls; let i = index;">
  <div [formGroupName]="i">
    <input formControlName="name" placeholder="Item name">
    <input formControlName="price" placeholder="Item price">
  </div>

  Chosen name: {{ productForm.controls.items.controls[i].controls.name.value }}
</div>
```

Comment: I dint quite understand on which part is the function that generates new input elements are located.

Comment: This is exactly the solution, I use this in multiple applications of mine. The function that generates new input elements is the createItem() function. You can even add validators to each input generated by this function like this: createItem(): FormGroup {
  return this.formBuilder.group({
    name: [undefined, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5), Validators.maxLength(40)]],
    price: [undefined, [Validators.required, Validators.customValidator1, Validators.customValidator2]]
  })
}. Don't forget to import FormArray in yout component.

Comment: Another suggestion. Keep your components as dumb as possible, put your http requests in services, and even better, make your components way more dumber by using ngrx store to keep all your app data in a single source of truth (redux concept), put all your business logic inside reducers, make your http calls and handle it's responses from ngrx @Effects. This is something everyone should strongly learn, because it makes your application really scalable, team work friendly and follows the best practices of functional programming. By doing this business logic becomes reusable in the whole app.